# Cmake in QtCreator: Source file not displayed in project file tree view

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

I'm using CMake och QtCreator to write C code. I open my project by opening the CMakeLists.txt file on the top level.
I see all the files in the project file tree view in QtCreator that are used to build executables or libraries like this:

```
add_library( my_lib file1.c )
add_executable( my_executable file2.c )
```

But I have one file that are used in precompilation for postgres like this:

```
set( MY_CMD "/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/ecpg" )
set( MY_ARG "file3.pgc" )
add_custom_target( dummy_target ALL COMMAND ${MY_CMD} ${MY_ARG} WORKING_DIRECTORY ${MY_DIR} )
```

The file file3.pgc is not displayed in the project file tree view. How can I make QtCreator find that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `SOURCES` option to `add_custom_target` (http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_target.html):

```
add_custom_target(dummy_target ALL 
    COMMAND ${MY_CMD} ${MY_ARG} 
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${MY_DIR} 
    SOURCES "${MY_DIR}/file3.pgc")
```

Comment: Is there any way to do the same if I use add_custom_command instead? @jet47

Comment: I am not sure. Still, if you use add_custom_command, you need to attach the output file to some target, so you can add source to this target.

Comment: No I use the output (a c-file) in add_library. @jet47

Comment: add_library(my_lib generated_file.c file3.pgc) actually builds. Isn't this just wrong!? file3.pgc shall not be built in to my_lib. @jet47

Comment: add_library builds only C/C++ sources, all other files are just added to IDE (for example headers).