# Visible files in the "Projects" View of the Qt Creator IDE if using the CMake build system

Tags: c++, qt, build, cmake, qt-creator

## Introduction

I am using the Integrated Development Environment (IDE) [Qt Creator](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator) v3.3.1
and the build system [CMake](http://cmake.org) v3.2.1 to develop in the C++ programming
language.

Currently I am implementing my own custom build "framework", so that I can use
the same *CMake* modules in each of my projects. The *framework* supports
generation of source files from CORBA and [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers) Interface Design
Language (IDL) files, for example. At the moment I am implementing support for
the [Qt Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5) v5.

The directory structure of my projects is as follows (using *Convention Over
Configuration*):

```
├── cmake              # Must contain source files of the custom "CMake"
│                      # framework (usually as a shared directory).
├── config             # May contain configuration files for the application.
├── doc                # May contain documentation files.
│   └── example        # May contain .cc files for example executables.
├── form               # May contain "Qt Framework" .ui files.
├── idl                # May contain CORBA .idl files.
├── include            # May contain .h files in an arbitrary directory
│                      # structure.
├── proto              # May contain "Protocol Buffers" .proto files.
├── src                # May contain .cc files in an arbitrary directory
│   │                  # structure.
│   └── main.cc        # Source definition file for the executable of the
│                      # application.
├── test               # May contain files for automated tests.
├── CHANGELOG
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── run_application.sh
└── run_build.sh
```

I used the *-nix command `tree` to produce the output above.

All directories, except the `cmake` directory containing the "framework" are
optional.

The "framework" builds an [Object Library](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#object-libraries) plus a static library (and
optionally a shared library) from the files in the `src` directory (ignoring
`src/main.cc` - which is always the source for the main executable application
- if it exist).

Therefore something like the following is done via *CMake* in the "framework":

```
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_objlib
            OBJECT ${PROJECT_DEFINITION_SOURCE_FILES_LIST})
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_staticlib
            STATIC
            $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROJECT_NAME}_objlib>)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_staticlib
                      ${PROJECT_LINK_LIBRARIES_LIST})
if(OPTION_BUILD_SHARED)
  add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_sharedlib
              SHARED
              $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROJECT_NAME}_objlib>)
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_sharedlib
                        ${PROJECT_LINK_LIBRARIES_LIST})
endif()
```

As you can see only the source definition files (`src/*.cc`) are used as an
input for the [`add_library`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/add_library.html) function.

## Problems

The build approach described above works nice from the command line, but in the
"Projects" View of *Qt Creator* only the following is visible:

- `cmake/*`
- `../*/usr/lib64/cmake/Qt5*`
- `form/*`
- `src/*`

I need a solution for the following two problems:

1. Show files and directories currently not visible in the "Projects" View of
   *Qt Creator*. In this case `config`, `doc`, `idl`, `include`, `proto`,
   `test`, `CHANGELOG`, `LICENSE` and `README.md`
2. Hide directories from the "Projects" View of *Qt Creator*. In this case
   `cmake` and the path to the *CMake* modules of *Qt5*.

After reading the following posts, it seems that no "clean" solution exists for
the problems described:

- [Cmake in QtCreator: Source file not displayed in project file tree view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27038988/cmake-in-qtcreator-source-file-not-displayed-in-project-file-tree-view):
  Using a "dummy" build target via the *CMake* function [`add_custom_target`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/add_custom_target.html).
- [QtCreator CMake project - how to show all project files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384935/qtcreator-cmake-project-how-to-show-all-project-files):
  Using the "File System" View in *Qt Creator*.
- [Is there any way to get QT Creator to show all of a project’s subdirectories?](http://answers.ros.org/question/56685/is-there-any-way-to-get-qt-creator-to-show-all-of-a-projects-subdirectories)

## Approaches

I've tried the following already;

- Adding all files that should be visible in the "Projects" View of *Qt Creator*
  as input to the `add_library` function of the *Object Library*: **Does not**
  work, since the following applies for an *Object Library*:

> Object libraries may contain only sources that compile, header files, and
>   other files that would not affect linking of a normal library (e.g. .txt).
>
> Adding all files that should be visible in the "Projects" View of *Qt Creator*
>   as input to the `add_library` function of the static library: **Does not**
>   work, since it causes the static library to be build "from scratch". The reason
>   is that the input files for the two `add_library` function calls differ with
>   this approach.
>
> Adding all files that should be visible in the "Projects" View of *Qt Creator*
>   as input to the `add_executable` function: **Does not** work, since I have
>   projects which do not build an executable.
>
> My current solution uses a "dummy" target:

```
# Parses the source files of the project to be correctly displayed in the
# "Projects" View of the Integrated Development Environment (IDE) "Qt Creator".
add_custom_target(qt_creator_parse_project
                  ALL SOURCES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_FILES_LIST})
```

The variable `PROJECT_SOURCE_FILES_LIST` contains the absolute path to all files
that should be visible in the "Projects" View of *Qt Creator*.

This works, the only flaw is that build target `qt_creator_parse_project` is
visible, e.g. if running `cmake --build . --target help`:

```
The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:
... all (the default if no target is provided)
... clean
... depend
... edit_cache
... rebuild_cache
... <PROJECT_NAME>
... qt_creator_parse_project
... [...]
```

## Questions

Finally, here are my two questions:

1. Does a better solution exists than using a "dummy" target to populate the
   "Projects" View of *Qt Creator* without modifying the behavior of the build
   process? If not, is it possible to hide the "dummy" target from the user?
2. Is it possible to ignore directories and folders automatically added to the
   "Projects" View of *Qt Creator* via *CMake*? If not, is it possible with *Qt
   Creator*?

Thanks for reading this long post. I wrote down all the details to make sure
other people do not run into the same problems.

Comment: Qt Creator uses cbp (Code Blocks Project) files provided by cmake. Maybe you need to search for similar problems with cmake + Code::Blocks.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov When loading CMake projects directly with the Qt Creator, the default generator on Linux and Mac is *Unix Makefiles* and on Windows it uses *NMAKE Makefiles*. To my knowledge CBP is not required.